# Tracking Algorithms

Tags: machine-learning

For my thesis I am implementing a tracking algorithm that tracks clusters of datapoints.

However, I have a hard time finding research papers and/or an overview of commonly used algoritms in this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your use of the word "tracking" may be leading your web queries off topic.  Are you interested in time-series?  Could you provide a simple example of "tracks clusters of datapoints"?

Using the word "tracks" do you mean over time, through space, or perhaps in reference to a chemical or physical process?

Further, with "clusters of datapoints", are you talking about objects (image recognition), are you talking about survey data & searching for trends, or something more akin to tracking the correlated movements of stock prices?

**Answer:** You might consider googling "Spatial Temporal Cluster Algorithms" or perhaps "Agent based modeling" or "Spatio-temporal point processes".  But again, the suggestions can be refined with a bit of insight on your desired application or context.

Comment: Thank you for answering, many voted, but not so many answered =) I have been looking at Multi Hypothesis Tracking for a while now. I will check out your suggestions, have not heard of two of them!